# why is purrr::map2 so slow compared to base mapply?

Tags: r, list, lapply, purrr

Consider this simple benchmark

```
list1 <- as.list(rep(1, 50))
list2 <- as.list(rep(1, 50))

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
+   map2(list1, list2, sum))
Unit: microseconds
                    expr    min       lq     mean   median      uq     max neval
 map2(list1, list2, sum) 375.31 384.2045 481.8708 407.8115 420.641 7923.58   100

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
+   mapply(sum, X=list1, Y=list2,  SIMPLIFY = FALSE))
Unit: microseconds
                                                expr    min     lq     mean  median      uq    max neval
 mapply(sum, X = list1, Y = list2, SIMPLIFY = FALSE) 46.187 50.634 57.45634 53.3715 59.8715 127.27   100
```

Why is `purrr:map2` almost **8 times slower** than `mapply` here? I mean, I am simply summing numbers side by side in the two lists.

The problem is that I am using `map2` in my current code, so I would like to understand what is the overhead here (and how to possibly fix it)

Thanks!

Comment: There may be a large difference in the overhead of calling each function, rather than in the data calculations themselves. If you run this on larger datasets, the speed ratio is much smaller. For example, if I run your code using the follow data `list1 <- as.list(rnorm(1e6));
list2 <- as.list(rnorm(1e6))`, then the medians are map: 1.34 seconds, mapply: 1.06 seconds. `map` is still slower, but the relative difference is much smaller.

Comment: Interestingly, using the million-value lists above and the function `function(X,Y) X+Y`, map is a bit faster than mapply: 1.02 sec vs. 1.25 sec., and their speed is very close when the lists have only 100 values (148 usec vs. 143 usec).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @eipi10 noted in the comments, there is some function call overhead that becomes less important when larger amounts of data are used:

```
list1 <- as.list(rep(1, 50000))
list2 <- as.list(rep(1, 50000))
microbenchmark(map2(list1, list2, sum), mapply(sum, X=list1, Y=list2,  SIMPLIFY = FALSE))
Unit: milliseconds
                                                expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
                             map2(list1, list2, sum) 73.84420 78.21917 82.53853 79.48526 81.28048 218.9266   100   b
 mapply(sum, X = list1, Y = list2, SIMPLIFY = FALSE) 51.92849 54.66514 61.34755 56.99206 58.67459 204.2119   100  a
```

`mapply` uses `.Internal` while `purr::map2` uses `.Call` to access the underlying C functions that do the processing. There are some differences in the way they work, particularly around argument evaluation, and the way R searches for the underlying code.

The R help on `.Internal` gives the cryptic message:

> .Internal performs a call to an internal code which is built in to the
>   R interpreter.
>
> Only true R wizards should even consider using this function, and only
>   R developers can add to the list of internal functions.

However, the R Internals manual explains that:

> C code compiled into R at build time can be called directly in what
>   are termed primitives or via the .Internal interface, which is very
>   similar to the .External interface except in syntax. More precisely, R
>   maintains a table of R function names and corresponding C functions to
>   call, which by convention all start with ‘do_’ and return a SEXP. This
>   table (R_FunTab in file src/main/names.c) also specifies how many
>   arguments to a function are required or allowed, whether or not the
>   arguments are to be evaluated before calling, and whether the function
>   is ‘internal’ in the sense that it must be accessed via the .Internal
>   interface, or directly accessible in which case it is printed in R as
>   .Primitive.

and

> A small number of primitives are specials rather than builtins, that
>   is they are entered with unevaluated arguments. This is clearly
>   necessary for the language constructs and the assignment operators, as
>   well as for && and || which conditionally evaluate their second
>   argument, and ~, .Internal, call, expression, missing, on.exit, quote
>   and substitute which do not evaluate some of their arguments.

The help file for `.Call` notes:

> If one of these functions is to be used frequently, do specify PACKAGE
>   (to confine the search to a single DLL) or pass .NAME as one of the
>   native symbol objects. Searching for symbols can take a long time,
>   especially when many namespaces are loaded.

Which implies that there is some time spent searching DLLs for functions when using `.Call`. It is worth noting that `purr::map2` does not specify the package name when using `.Call` and doing so may reduce the overhead required.